# Python Decorator for registering tags ins class

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, decorator

I have a class that mostly provides properties for interfacing data stored in a dictionary. Each property is responsible for (usually) one key in the dictionary, but there may be additional keys in the dictionary, that are not managed by properties.

Edit 3: To clarify, as there has been some confusion in the comments:

> I have an arbitrary set of keys, for which I have a fixed subset of
>   keys for which getters/setters are implemented, but the
>   getters/setters are NOT identical in any meaningful way. I want a way
>   to know for which keys I have defined such a getter/setter without
>   having to maintain a separate list. It is more maintainable to just
>   "tag" the getter/setter/property with the key it is responsible for
>   and generate a list of managed keys from the tags. Also I hoped that I
>   could then have a variable name in the getter/setter body that
>   contains the property name, as to avoid typos.

Most properties look something like this, **but they may do more complex tasks such as converting data types**

```py
        @property
        def name(self) -> str:
            return self.header['MYKEY'] if 'MYKEY' in self.header else ""

        @name.setter
        def name(self, value: str):
            self.header['MYKEY'] = value
```

I now would like to have an additional decorator `@RegisterProperty('MYKEY')` that

1. provides the get/set functions with an additional argument that contains the name of the key (i.e. the first argument of the decorator), as to avoid typos. Similar to how `@classmethod` adds the "hidden" argument `cls` to the function.
2. Adds the key (again, first argument of the decorator) in a set of the containing class of the property, so i can do `myclass.registered_properties` to see what key values are "managed" through properties and which ones aren't.

From what I've read about decorators, the way to go is to define a class-based  decorator inside the class that I want to use it in (as I cannot create a function based decorator in the class, as it would become a method or something). I can modify the signature of the wrapped class method (property getter setter) through the `*args,**kwargs` arguments, and i can also extract `self` from those as to write `myclass.registered_properties`.

But

1. where do I gain access to the argument of the decorator?
2. How can i "initialize" `myclass.registered_properties`, as `self` is only available during runtime and I don't want to check for it's existence every time (for performance reasons, mostly).

**Edit1**: After reading [this](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html) I got this prototype for a decorator:

```py
class PropertyRegister:
    def __init__(self, parent, property_name):
        self.property_name = property_name
        parent.registered_properties.add(property_name)

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            args.insert(0, self.property_name)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        return wrapped_f
```

But still not sure how to ensure the existence of `parent.registered_properties`.

**Edit2**: As pointed out in the comments, the prototype decorator doesn't work, as `self` cannot be passed to `parent` for the decorator, as it doesn't exist yet at this point. Here's an updated version that intercepts `self` from the function call itself. Bit ugly however.

```py
    class PropertyRegister:
        def __init__(self, property_name):
            self.property_name = property_name

        def __call__(self, func):
            def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
                parent = args[0]
                parent.registered_properties.add(self.property_name)
                args.insert(1, self.property_name)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
            return wrapped_f

...

        @RegisterProperty('MYKEY')
        @property
        def name(self, property_name) -> str:
            return self.header[property_name] if property_name in self.header else ""

        @RegisterProperty('MYKEY')
        @name.setter
        def name(self, property_name, value: str):
            self.header[property_name] = value
```

Problem with this is that the property will only be registered, once the getter/setter is actually called.

Comment: I think decorator is not relevant way to achieve it: better maybe to use metaclass or `__new__()` bcz what do you want to decorate? It's something one, and what should it be? But it's easy to generate getters/setters functions in `__new__()` based on class attribute `magic_props` which is list of string. If it's empty then no properties: one item = one property.  PS. you can use `self.header.get("something", "")` for default empty string for missing properties

Comment: @Paul-AG thanks for reminding me of `.get`! Regarding auto-generating getters/setters. I actually did do exactly that. But after a while I got frustrated with the lack of autocompletion-integration of this method and also many properties need to convert data types or perform side effects. So autogenerating became less and less interesting. I don't quite get the first part of your comment. I want to decorate the getters/setters.

Comment: such decorator will decorate getter and setter with the same string value for property name, right (twice)? So, it does not help you to "avoid typos" is the name. IMHO better is to generate getters and setters in the `__new__()`. Also you have an option with `__getattr__()` and `__getattribute__()`

Comment: What is supposed to be "parent" in you snippet ? The containing class ? It doesn't exist yet...

Comment: I suggest you take some time reading on 1/ [the class creation process](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) and 2/ [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). This should give you some hindsight on how to best solve your problem, specially the "registering" part (hint: it aint gonna work with only decorators and descriptors, you'll need to hook into the class creation process), as well as improving your comprehension of Python's object model.

Comment: @Paul-AG it will not completely solve the typo risk but reduce it, as the hard coded string is used less often. Anyway, I mostly want this for knowing for which keys a property exists. I still don't see how generating properties in `__new__` solves my problems, especially those listed in my previous comment. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: About the autocompletion: if you are talking about autocompletion in IPython, Jupyter or the interactive interpreter, you can provide the properties you want to autocomplete by implementing the `__dir__(self)` method. It must return a list of the names of the properties. This does not help if you need the autocompletion in a static context like PyCharm, though.

Comment: It is unclear to me how you would use your proposed decorator. Could you show an example of it being used?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, it was a bit foolish to assume i could just pass `self` to the decorator.. I looked at the class creation process but I didn't get much out of it. Perhaps you are trying to point me at metaclasses? The descriptor protocol just seems to cover the underlying mechanics of properties, but again I fail to see the pointer to the solution I seek..

Comment: @Wombatz, yes I'm talking about PyCharm autocompletion. An example of usage of the (illegal) property would be just `PropertyRegister(self, 'MYKEY')` over `@property` and `@name.setter`.

Comment: Do i understand this correctly: you have a fixed set of keys. For each key you want a gettable and settable property on your class, all the getters and setters will be implemented identically (only difference is the value of the key) and you want a short way to define them all?

Comment: @Wombatz. No, i have an arbitrary set of keys, for which I have a fixed subset of keys for which getters/setters are implemented, but the getters/setters are NOT identical in any meaningful way. I want a way to know for which keys I have defined such a getter/setter without having to maintain a separate list. It is more maintainable to just "tag" the getter/setter/property with the key it is responsible for and generate a list of managed keys from the tags. Also I hoped that I could then have a variable name in the getter/setter body that contains the property name, as to avoid typos.

Comment: @Xaser cf my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Q&D possible implementation using a custom property-like descriptor and a class decorator to collect registered keys (you may also use a custom metaclass instead):

```
class FlaggedProperty():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self._key = key
        self._getter = None
        self._setter = None

    def __call__(self, getter):
        self._getter = getter
        return self

    def setter(self, setter):
        self._setter = setter
        return self

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return self._getter(obj, self._key)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self._setter is None:
            raise AttributeError("Attribute is read-only")
        self._setter(obj, self._key, value)


def register_flagged_properties(cls):
    cls.registered_properties = set()
    for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:
        parent_properties = getattr(parent, "registered_properties", None)
        if parent_properties:
            cls.registered_properties.update(parent_properties)
    for item in cls.__dict__.values():
        if isinstance(item, FlaggedProperty):
            cls.registered_properties.add(item._key)
    return cls
```

And how it's used:

```
@register_flagged_properties
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @FlaggedProperty("foo")
    def foo(self, key):
        return self.data.get(key, None)

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
```

> I looked at the class creation process but I didn't get much out of it. Perhaps you are trying to point me at metaclasses?

Well, first and mainly, you have to understand how a class is created at runtime to understand what is available at which point of the process. And yes, metaclasses was supposed to be part of the possible answers - together with the `init_subclass` hook or [class decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) (I mean: "decorators applied to classes", not "decorators defined as classes").

> The descriptor protocol just seems to cover the underlying mechanics of properties, but again I fail to see the pointer to the solution I seek.

It's not only used by properties - it's also (and much more importantly) the support for methods (both instancememethods and classmethods), and for any custom descriptor.

Comment: Beautiful! I'm going to test this right away, likely with @wombatz modifications. I'll try to spend more time on understanding class creation and the descriptor protocol, thanks. One question however: could you not just derive `FlaggedProperty` from `Property` and override the required methods?

Comment: @Xaser you'd end up overriding almost everything so what's the point ?-)

Comment: Fair enough, just thought about establishing some "relationship" to a normal property.

Comment: @Xaser well it's named "FlaggedProperty" and behaves mostly like a property so that should be enough of a hint ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to bruno's answer. If you are using python 3.6 or later, you can ommit the `register_flagged_properties` decorator and let the `FlaggedProperty` instances register themselves.

Simply add this method to the `FlaggesProperty` class.

```
def __set_name__(self, cls, name):
    # cls is the class where the decorator is used
    # name is the function name
    try:
        cls.registered_properties.add(self._key)
    except AttributeError:
        cls.registered_properties = {self._key}
```

The name is a bit misleading in my opinion, but the method is called for every tagged property when the class is created.

You could even use the python name as the key if you want.  For this change the `__init__` method to:

```
def __init__(self, getter):
    self._key = None
    self._getter = getter
    self._setter = None
```

Delete the `__call__` method and in `__set_name__` add this line:

```
def __set_name__(self, cls, name):
    self._key = name
    # leave the rest unchanged
```

Now you can use the decorator like this:

```
class Foo:
    @FlaggedProperty
    def bar(self, key):
        # key now contains the string "bar"

    # leave the rest unchanged
```

Comment: I definitly need to switch to Python3 !-)

Comment: Very cool modification! Gave an upvote but likely will accept @brunodesthuilliers answer, as he came up with the original concept.

Answer (score 0):

With metaclass:

```py
class MetaX(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for k in dct["keys"]:
            fget = lambda self, k=k: self.header.get(k, "")
            fset = lambda self, value, k=k: self.header.__setitem__(k, value)
            prop = property(fget, fset)
            dct[k] = prop
        obj = super(MetaX, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        return obj

class X(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaX
    keys = "mykey1", "mykey2", "mykey3"

    def __init__(self):
        self.header = {"mykey1": 123}


x = X()
print x.mykey1, x.mykey2
x.mykey1 = 900
print x.mykey1, x.mykey2
```

Comment: " the getters/setters are NOT identical in any meaningful way."